# All permutation that commute with (1 4 5 2 ) (3 6) in S6?

Tags: permutations

How can i find all the permutations that commute with a given permutation. I know about the trick with multiplying by the inverse of the permutation but i don t know how to apply it? Can someone offer a step by step explanation?

Comment: Since your permutation is written as disjoint cycles, any permutation that commutes with each of these cycles permutes with the entire element.

Comment: And how can i find what permutations can commute with my disjoint cycles?

Comment: Well, when does a cycle commute with another permutation? When the other permutation is a power of that cycle, or when the permutation doesn't touch any of the same elements as the cycle. Perhaps even the product of two such permutations.